# Show that a matrix $A$ is symmetric positive semidefinite iff there exists a symmetric matrix $B$ such that $B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

There is a hint here that says to use the diagonal form of the matrix $A$.

Comment: As stated, the statement is wrong. Take $A=0_n$, $B=0_n$. $B$ is symmetric and $A=B^2$, yet $A$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Clement C. you are right. After reading again the question it says that A is symmetric positive semidefinite.

Comment: OK -- the edit solves the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is positive semidefinite, then $A=V\Lambda V^*$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and positive semidefinite, and $V$ is unitary. Then, if $\sqrt\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix with the square roots of the elements of $\Lambda$, then $B=V\sqrt\Lambda V^*$, and $B^2=A$.

On the other hand, if $A=B^2$ and $B$ is symmetric, then $B=V\Lambda V^*$, and $A=B^2=V\Lambda V^*V\Lambda V^*=V\Lambda^2 V^*$. Since $B$ is symmetric, $\Lambda$ is real, and then $\Lambda^2$ is positive semidefinite, so that $A$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: For the converse part, where is it assumed that $B$ is positive?

Comment: In saying that there exists $V$ and $\Lambda$, with $V$ unitary (or orthogonal if you're using just real numbers) and $\Lambda$ diagonal and positive, such that $B=V\Lambda V^*$.

Comment: B is symmetric but non necessarily positive

Comment: @fonini *You* said it. The statement does not assume $B$ is positive, *you* decided to assume it (and the statement is wrong).

Comment: Oh, $B$ is not necessarily positive, I'll amend it.

Comment: There. It's not a great deal, actually.

Comment: It sort of is -- you can prove semidefinite positive, *not* positive (the statement the OP asks to prove is wrong with positive definite).

Comment: @fonini After correcting the statement, in which the matrix A is symmetric positive semidefinite and B is just symmetric matrix, can I assume your approach is complete? thank you very much.

Comment: Yes. You should pay attention to @ClementC. 's comment, in noting that you are only proving that $A$ is semidefinite.